# Expand the height of grand-parent div for dynamic content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

First of all I want to say that I am not good in css. Here is my scenerio-

```
Grandparent div(cd-timeline-block)
--------------------------------------------------------------------

left-Parent(cd-timeline-content) right parent(cd-timeline-img)
----------------------------     --------

child 1 of left-parent(content)                  child 2 of leftparent
                                                (cd-layer-2)
----------------------------                     ---------------
```

This scenerio is generating for dynamic content in a for-loop. But the problem is always grandparent div taking the height of "child 1 of left-parent div" and creating next block according to that height.. in some cases "child2 left parent" content is bigger, in that case the next block appear on top of child 2.

here is my code:

```
<div class="cd-timeline-block">
    <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
    </div>
    <div class="cd-timeline-content">
         <div class="content">
         </div>
         <div class="cd-layer2">
             <div class="content-2">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.cd-timeline-block {
 position: relative;
 margin: 1em 0;
height: auto;
}

.cd-timeline-img {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -29px;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}   

.cd-timeline-content {
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 45%;
 position: relative;
}

.content {
 position: relative;
}

.cd-timeline-content .cd-layer2 {
font-size: 1em;
left: 121%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
}

.content-2 {
margin-left: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

I want to get the max height between "child 1 of left-parent(content)" and "child 2 of left-parent(cd-layer2)" and display the next grandparent(cd-timeline-block) according that height. Here want to mention again that the height of child 1 and child2 can be varied according to the dynamic content, so I can not fix the height..

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by javascript. Though using js to solve css problem is not elegant and i am not liking it. very appreciable if anyone give me more elegant way.

```
    var setHeight1 = $(".cd-timeline-content").height();
    var setHeight2 = $(".cd-layer2").height();
    if (setHeight2 > setHeight1) {
        $(".cd-timeline-content").height(setHeight2);
    };
```